# Boosting classification tree in R

Tags: r, classification, boosting

I'm trying to boost a classification tree using the `gbm` package in R and I'm a little bit confused about the kind of predictions I obtain from the `predict` function.

Here is my code:

```
  #Load packages, set random seed
  library(gbm)
  set.seed(1)

  #Generate random data
  N<-1000
  x<-rnorm(N)
  y<-0.6^2*x+sqrt(1-0.6^2)*rnorm(N)
  z<-rep(0,N)
  for(i in 1:N){
    if(x[i]-y[i]+0.2*rnorm(1)>1.0){
      z[i]=1
    }
  }

  #Create data frame
  myData<-data.frame(x,y,z)

  #Split data set into train and test
  train<-sample(N,800,replace=FALSE)
  test<-(-train)

  #Boosting
  boost.myData<-gbm(z~.,data=myData[train,],distribution="bernoulli",n.trees=5000,interaction.depth=4)
  pred.boost<-predict(boost.myData,newdata=myData[test,],n.trees=5000,type="response")
  pred.boost
```

`pred.boost` is a vector with elements from the interval `(0,1)`.

I would have expected the predicted values to be either `0` or `1`, as my response variable `z` also consists of dichotomous values - either `0` or `1` - and I'm using `distribution="bernoulli"`.

How should I proceed with my prediction to obtain a real classification of my test data set? Should I simply round the `pred.boost` values or is there anything I'm doing wrong with the `predict` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observed behavior is correct. From documentation:

> If type="response" then gbm converts back to the same scale as the
>   outcome. Currently the only effect this will have is returning
>   probabilities for bernoulli.

So you should be getting probabilities when using `type="response"` which is correct. Plus `distribution="bernoulli"` merely tells that labels follows bernoulli (0/1) pattern. You can omit that and still model will run fine.

To proceed do `predict_class <- pred.boost > 0.5` (cutoff = 0.5) or else plot ROC curve to decide on cutoff yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How about multinomial Y instead of binary Y? In that case, how shall I code to return the label with the highest probability?

Answer (score 0):

Try using adabag. Class, probabilities, votes and error are inbuilt in adabag which makes it easy to interpret, and of course less lines of codes.